# Identical values of bathymetric data

Tags: qgis, slope, bathymetry

I downloaded gridded bathymetric data from GEBCO, from which I calculated a slope map using QGIS and then examined the resulting values using the 'raster layer unique values report' function. I found that for a subset of values, specifically up to 80 out of over 280,000 pixels, the numerical values matched up to the 8th decimal point. I then checked the original data from GEBCO (which btw I previously transformed from WGS84 to UTM 56N) and discovered that there were depth values that were identical up to the 6th decimal point (e.g., the value -5789.43212891 appeared 7 times).

Is that a common occurrence? I would not be surprised if some pixels coincide up to the 2nd decimal. However, up to the 5th decimal seems a bit too much of a coincidence.

Comment: Computers store numbers in a binary form. Try https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html. Value -5789.432 is changing into -5789.43212890625 when stored as a floating point number.